# Indefinite integration and definite integration calculation

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

Given the functions:

$A(x)=B(2x-1)-B(2x)$

B(x) is a function as x->infinity, limit of B(x)->0.

for $b>1$ find out:

$$\int_{b}^\infty A(x) dx - \frac12\int_{2b-1}^{2b} B(x) dx$$

The answer is $0$. But why?

I attempted to do:

$\int_{b}^\infty A(x) dx=\int_{b}^\infty B(2x-1)-B(2x) dx$

$=\int_{b}^\infty \sum_{k=2x-1}^{2x} B(k) dx$

And I think that it would be possible to swap the summation and integration, however got no further...

Comment: Isn't the first integral $\int_b^\infty A(x)dx$ divergent?

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo: Indeed, it is divergent because for $x > {\rm e}^2$ we have $\ln (1 + \ln x) > 1$, so $\int \limits _{{\rm e}^2} ^\infty A(x) {\rm d} x \sim \int  \limits _{{\rm e}^2} ^\infty \frac 1 {\sqrt[3] x} {\rm d} x = \infty$.

Comment: Please clarify your question; as it is now it is most probably mistaken.

Comment: I know A(x) and B(x) are all diverges, but that has no impact if we don't try to calculate it directly, right? There's a relation between A(x) and B(x).

Comment: Not quite: $B$ is a continuous function, so it is bounded on $[2b-1,2b]$, therefore its integral will be finite. The first integral, on the other hand, is infinite, as it has been explained above. Therefore your expression is $+\infty$ - not exactly what you wanted to obtain.

Comment: You all have a point, I will ask my teacher to clarify a little bit. :)

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is my answer (I modified the question as the B(x)= part is not quite useful):

let m=2x-1, n=2x

Then integral of A(x)=$\int_{2b-1}^\infty B(m) dm - \int_{2b}^\infty B(n) dn$

Then equals the integral at the right hand side.

Comment: And the answer just got confirmed by teacher.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full solution, but almost. Define
$$
I(b)=\int_{b}^\infty [B(2x-1)-B(2x)]dx - \frac12\int_{2b-1}^{2b} B(x) dx\ .
$$
For a *generic* $B(x)$ [not necessarily the one the OP wrote], we have
$$
\frac{d}{db}I(b)=0
$$
identically, using the fundamental theorem of calculus. Indeed
$$
\frac{d}{db}\int_b^\infty dx B(2x-1)=-B(2b-1)
$$
$$
\frac{d}{db}\int_b^\infty dx B(2x)=-B(2b)
$$
$$
\frac{d}{db}\int_{2b-1}^{2b}B(x)dx=2 B(2 b)-2 B(2 b-1)\ .
$$
Therefore, $I(b)$ is a constant (as a function of $b$). So, you only need to evaluate your $I(b)$ at a value of $b$ of your choice [pick a value for which the computation is easy] to establish your claim....

Comment: I don't know how you get $\frac {d}{db} I(b)=0$...

Comment: @Jie Li are you familiar with the fundamental theorem of calculus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus ?

Comment: Yes, but b is a constant, what to get when you do a differentiation on constant?

Comment: No, wait a second...$b$ is a constant *once you substitute a numerical value to it* (like $b=5$ or $b=0.34$)...if you don't substitute a numerical value to it, it is just a variable, so you can consider $I(b)$ as a function of the (yet unspecified) value of $b$. What you are saying is like saying that you cannot differentiate $f(x)=x^2$ with respect to $x$ because, if you substitute $x=5$, you get $f(5)=25$ and $(d/dx)25=0$, which clearly does not make much sense!